# How do I dispose of unused java UI objects

Tags: java, swing

I have a swing app that 'spawns' a number of class objects - let's call them 'actors'.  From time to time during the program's run, those objects are destroyed from the UI perspective, but I'm not sure how to handle disposal of the object from the application perspective.

To describe the situation better, there are instances of class actor represented on a game board.  When one of those pieces are logically destroyed from the game perspective, they disappear from the game board, but from the app perspective, the object's execute code still fires during a reschedule.  Oversimplified sample code:

```
package ext;
public abstract class Actor implements Comparable<Actor> {
...
    public void execute();{
       //execute code goes here
    }
}

package ext;
public class EXT extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        myactor = new Actor();
}
```

So a new actor is spawned ever 30 seconds and there can be up to 40 actors on the board at any one time... when an actor is logically eliminated, how do I stop the actor.execute routine from firing for that instance of actor every time?  Or do I have to set a bitflag for the actor to say it has been destroyed and use an if in the actor.execute routine to check that bitflag every time it fires?

Comment: You have a few choices, you could have a pool of actors from which you can draw, placing them into an "active" queue, these get "executed", when done, the unused actor is placed back into the pool. This means you reduce the overhead of the object creation each time. You could have a upper/lower limit on the pool, when it's "full" you simply discard the actor reference (remove all references to it) and allow the GC to take over. Alternativly you could simply do the last stage, remove any references to the actor and let the GC take care of it.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer will depend on what the actors are doing (can they be re-used) and how they are "executed". One assumes you have some kind of queue which you loop over and "execute" each actor (or something similar), if so, then simply removing the actor from this queue will stop it from been executed

Comment: What is the correct way to discard the actor reference?  myactor = null doesn't seem to actually get rid of that instance, the execute() routine still seems to continue firing at regular intervals for that instance of actor...

Comment: Then something is still referencing the object. A object with no references to it, which also references objects which are not reference by any other objects becomes eligible for GC. You have to make sure that the object itself is not referencing anything that might be keeping it alive and that their are no direct or indirect strong references to it

Comment: OK great, that sounds feasible.  Let me look into the state of the object at the time it's reference is set to null.  I'll come back and add the answer here if it's sorted as it likely is.